# inner join query selecting from database where lang is en

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have one query with inner join that take a question and 4 answers from the db. I want to make this query to take only the questions that lang table is 'en'
This is the query:

```
$mysql->query("SELECT Q.id AS id, Q.question, QA.answer1, QA.answer2,
                      QA.answer3, QA.answer4, QA.correct, QC.name AS cat_name 
               FROM question Q
                   INNER JOIN question_answers QA ON QA.questionFK=Q.id
                   INNER JOIN question_cats QC ON QC.id=Q.categoryFK
               ORDER BY rand()
               LIMIT 1");
```

I try to make it like this:

```
$mysql->query("SELECT Q.id AS id, Q.question, QA.answer1, QA.answer2, 
                      QA.answer3, QA.answer4, QA.correct, QC.name AS cat_name 
                FROM question Q
                   INNER JOIN question_answers QA ON QA.questionFK=Q.id
                   INNER JOIN question_cats QC ON QC.id=Q.categoryFK
                WHERE Q.lang='en'
                ORDER BY rand()
                LIMIT 1");
```

But it didn't work, it's select everyting...
Where am i wrong and how should i make it?

Those are the 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cnt` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `correct` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `categoryFK` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `from_userFK` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `correct_points` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ut` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `del` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `lang` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question_answers` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `questionFK` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `answer1` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
  `answer2` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
  `answer3` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
  `answer4` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
  `correct` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `ut` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `del` enum('yes','no') CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;
```

Comment: Can you include a description of your tables?

Comment: Sorry, didnt understund what exactly do you need?

Comment: The structure of your tables. Preferably the output of a `DESCRIBE` query like: `DESCRIBE question_answers`

Comment: Why this wastage: `ORDER BY rand()` and then `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: SQL looks correct to me.   are questions, categories and answers all dependant on the question language? or does each table have it's own language.  If each table, then your joins on the tables need to include language

Comment: I have 2 tables the first is with the question, category and lang
The second is with 4 answers
I don't know how to explane it to you.. Should i post the database tables?

Answer (score 0):

To me it feels like your filer condition `WHERE Q.lang='en'` doesn't matches any record and so the outcome. Consider trimming it before comparing like

```
            WHERE TRIM(Q.lang) ='en'
```

Comment: It's not working... Right now i have 2 questions in the database one is with lang 'en' the other is with lang 'bg' it's should show only the question with lang en but it's show both....

Comment: Can you post some sample data from `question` table?